# Windows 7 Extend C Volume to Unallocated Space

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, partitioning, disk-management

A while back I installed Ubuntu and then later uninstalled it by I think deleting the partitions and recovering the windows 7 boot loader. I am not that experienced with partitioning yet. As you can see here there are two partitions that are now unallocated.

[image]

The 9gb one is a recovery or something that came with the computer. How can I extend my C partition to use both of those? I do not want to have that much storage just wasted sitting there.

Currently when I right click on C and hit extend the wizard pops up but there is no available space to extend.

[image]

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Thank you Jason Aller for turning my links into pictures! It said I couldn't post pictures without a certain amount of posts or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> to get the run box, type `diskmgmt.msc` and press <kbd>enter</kbd>.

- Just click with right mouse button on the Ubuntu partition, and
  choose to Delete Volume.
- If Windows 7 was preinstalled on your computer, please ensure you
  don't remove recovery partitions, etc.
- The space formerly occupied by Linux should now say "Unallocated".
- And Now Right-click on C: and "Extend Volume" to increase the size of
  drive C using the unallocated space.
- If you were using grub to dual-boot (most probably), then you may
  need the windows CD to fix the boot manager and make Windows 7
  bootable again.

How to fix your boot manager :

1. boot your system using windows installation cd
2. go to "repair your system"
3. use command prompt
4. type `bootrec /fixboot` then hit enter
5. type `bootrec /fixmbr` then hit enter
6. exit

This time your system will boot directly into windows.

This is the safe way to uninstall Ubuntu.